# PG::ConnectionBad fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Disclaimer: I'm very new to programming in general, so please excuse my sizeable ignorance.
I'm trying to run an application I've written in rails, but when I do, I get the error "fe_sendauth: no password supplied".
Here's my database.yml, I have a feeling it's something in here.

```
default: &default
    adapter: postgresql
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
    database: url-shortener_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: url-shortener_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: url-shortener_production
  username:
  password:
```

Comment: It means you are not providing the username and password for the development environment. Create a user and set a password for postgres by referring https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Comment: Show your `pg_hba.conf` file

Comment: @rick, here it is, as far as I can tell. Other users seem to have theirs in different locations.  

   `# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD  
  
    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only  
    local   all             all                                     trust  
    # IPv4 local connections:  
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust  
    # IPv6 local connections:  
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust`
Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: You might have to create new roles in database . Are you able to login to postgresql shell ?

Comment: @Caffeine Coder No, I've been trying that for the last hour or so, no luck. I must have created a login at some point, but I have absolutely no memory of it.

Comment: ok , do you have the username password for the database in local ?

Comment: You can uninstall postgresql and again install it , this time remember the credentials . Also , there's a nice tool availaible called PgAdmin3 in ubuntu software centre , it's very useful .

Comment: @CaffeineCoder Yeah, I guess that's what I'll have to do. God, things really start to spiral once you think you can fix something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this,

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

to,

```
local   all             all                                     md5
```

and create a super_user in PostgreSQL with `username` and `password`, and add that `username` and `password` to your `database.yml` file

Comment: Where to find this pls?

Comment: /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf  or /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 0):

Please do some changes in database.yml

development:

```
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: database-name
  pool: 5
  username: ####  your pg username
  password: ####  your pg password
```

Comment: Thanks, but it hasn't fixed anything. :/