# Rails and postgresql - no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I cannot figure out why I am constantly getting this error when running `rake db:migrate:status` after switching over to Postgresql and Rails 5.2.1

```
[root:7e2d33988106:~/myapp]# rake db:migrate:status                                                                                                                                                                                                      12:04AM/06.27
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:692:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:223:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:48:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:48:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:811:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:855:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:834:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:795:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:523:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1014:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:22:in `table_exists?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:124:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:status
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**What I've done so far**

I have edited the `pg_hba.conf` file to show the following:

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

and restarted the service. No luck. Same error. The first error I got prior to this was invalid password for postgresql, so i had to change one of the "peer" options to "md5"

If I look into my `config/database.yml` file, this is what it looks like:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: unicode
  username: postgres
  database: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:database, Rails.env.to_sym, :database_name) %>
  # username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:database, Rails.env.to_sym, :database_user_name) %>
  # password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:database, Rails.env.to_sym, :database_password) %>

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

staging:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

and when I edit the credentials with `rake` (using `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`), this is what this file looks like:

```
# aws:
#   access_key_id: 123
#   secret_access_key: 345

# Used as the base secret for all MessageVerifiers in Rails, including the one protecting cookies.
secret_key_base: <my long key redacted for stackoverflow>
database:
 development:
   database_name: development
   database_user_name: postgres
   database_password: <redacted for stackoverflow>
 test:
   database_name: test
   database_user_name: postgres
   database_password: <redacted for stackoverflow>
 production:
   database_name: production
   database_user_name: postgres
   database_password: <redacted for stackoverflow>
```

I feel like I've been going hours deep down the rabbit hole and cannot figure out how to get this Rails application working with Postgresql.

I have taken a look at this post here: [PG::ConnectionBad fe_sendauth: no password supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450558/pgconnectionbad-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied) and have tried its suggestion with no luck, and even here [How to resolve the error 'fe_sendauth: no password supplied' in Rails using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593451/how-to-resolve-the-error-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied-in-rails-using-post) with no luck either. I don't have `host: ''` or `host: 'localhost'` anywhere in the `config/database.yml` file (I've tried adding it and still didn't work), so I'm not quite sure this has anything to do with anything here for me.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: do u have `gem 'pg'` in your gem file?

Comment: Sure do. @AbhishekAravindan

Comment: i had the similar problem, i don't remember what i actually did to solve, Please give a try to provide username and password in `production:` in `database.yml`

Comment: It's funny you mention that, @AbhishekAravindan because I just added `username` and `password` in `config/database.yml` and it worked perfectly fine. I'm not sure why this has problems when using the new authentication process.

Comment: happy to here that worked.... i will post as a answer :)

Comment: Is there a way to get this working using the new Rails 5.2 way rather than putting the plaintext in the database.yml file?

Comment: you can add in RAILS_ENV variable

Comment: Gotcha. Sounds great. Thanks!

Comment: welcome.feel free to comment if it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your username and password in `production:` in `database.yml`